# Updating an ArrayAttribute with ReactJs

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

**EDITED:**
renamed *shouldComponentUpdate* to *onClick*

I'm using Ruby on Rails with the gem *react-rails*. The idea is to use a "PATCH" method to update an `ArrayAttribute` but using just JavaScript. To be clear, I'm still a newbie building a project while learning.

The story is, when a user checks a checkbox, it marks their post as complete. Their Post's table has a column for `is_complete: :boolean, :default => false`. Im using Postgres for the database.

```
var Foo = React.createClass({
 getInitialState: function() {
   return {
     is_complete: this.props.data.is_complete, # shows "Empty object"
     # is_complete: this.props.data[0].is_complete ..... shows "false"
     # I could not use that because data[0] and data[1] etc...
   }
 },

 onClick: function(){
   var newVal = this.state.is_complete;
   this.setState({
      is_complete: React.addons.update(this.state.is_complete, { '$set': [ newVal ] })
    })
 },

 render: function() {
  var supports = (s) => (
   <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.onClick}
      /> Mark complete
  );   
  return (
   <div>
     {this.props.data.map(supports)}
   </div>
  );
 }
});
```

**Index.html.erb:**

```
<%= react_component('Foo', { data: @userlist }) %>
```

**controller:**

```
@userlist = @user.supports.as_json(:only => [:is_complete] # shortened for emample
```

When the checkbox is checked I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of is_complete of undefined`

I'm looping through all of that user's posts (supports) and outputting the result on one page with a checkbox to mark as complete. I could achieve something similar by adding the chechbox inside of the edit page but I don't want that.

After the edit, I'm not getting the result I want. I want when checked, Array[1] and [2]'s is_complete is set to true or false.

Somehow I need to loop the `getInitialState()`, is that possible? I see not documentation on that.

Comment: It would probably be better not to use the name `shouldComponentUpdate` for your `onChange` method.  `shouldComponentUpdate` is a documented React lifecycle method that is used by React to determine whether or not to re-render the component.  Your issue is most likely due to the fact that React will call this method before rendering the component (and state is not available).

Comment: Yes, do not override `shouldComponentUpdate` for that purpose, for now do not override it at all. Change your method name to something like `onCheckboxChange`. `createClass` should autobind it, but if it's not working still check that your context `this` is the instance of the class

Comment: I have edited the post. I've also change `$push` to `$set`